# What does "fall out of heaven" mean?

Tags: lyrics

I was searching around i could not find anything. I heard it in a song, maybe it's a metaphor or idiom. I don't know. The song's from Kanye West & The-Dream. The-Dream is sayin'

> No one wants to fall out of heaven

The song is also called like that

Maybe do you know what that means?

Comment: Might also be a reference to a common pick-up line: "Did it hurt?" "Did what hurt?" "Did it hurt when you fell from heaven?"

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that this is a reference to the common idea of Satan as a fallen angel.

In Luke 10:18 Jesus says "I saw Satan fall like lightning from heaven."

Comment: ... or to the concept of [fallen angels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallen_angel) in general.